Image overflow from div
My images overflow from the div box.I have made a nav-bar of height 160 and added two images in it.I have declared a box and flexbox and added justify-content:space-between. Whenever I try to put both images in a div box it get overflow from my nav-bar and do not respect the height given to it.
I can't understand the problem as I remove both images from div it don;t overflow and remains in the height of nav-bar.Can someone tell me why this happened and what is the solution to it?
The code is here:


*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.nav-bar{
    height:160px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px red solid;
    position:fixed;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.header-img{
    border:1px blue solid;
}
<div class="container">
   <div class="nav-bar flex">
      <div class="header-img">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="header-list">
         <ul class="flex">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="search">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search here">
         <input type="button" value="submit">
      </div>
      <div class="header-img">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>




You code does not demonstrate the problem nor does it include display:flex.

add div style clear both after img tag
<div class="header-img">
         <img src="https://picsum.photos/20/20.jpg">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
      </div>

